# ORA-29280: invalid directory path returned when executing code in a pl/sql package works fine as an anonymous block

Tags: oracle, plsql

The exact same code works in an anonymous block but not in a procedure or package.

```
SQL> 
SQL> declare
  2         my_file_handle       UTL_FILE.file_type;
  3  BEGIN
  4           my_file_handle := UTL_FILE.fopen ('UT_PROCESS_LOG_DIR', 'wtf.log', 'A');
  5           UTL_FILE.put_line (my_file_handle, 'wtf');
  6           utl_file.fclose (my_file_handle);
  7  END;
  8  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> 
SQL> create or replace procedure test_dir as
  2           my_file_handle           UTL_FILE.file_type;
  3  BEGIN
  4           my_file_handle := UTL_FILE.fopen ('UT_PROCESS_LOG_DIR', 'wtf.log', 'A');
  5           UTL_FILE.put_line (my_file_handle, 'wtf');
  6           utl_file.fclose (my_file_handle);
  7  END;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> show errors
No errors.
SQL> 
SQL> exec test_dir;
BEGIN test_dir; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29280: invalid directory path
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 41
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 478
ORA-06512: at "SA.TEST_DIR", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

---

I don't know how adding any text will make this a better post but without a higher ratio of comments to code, stackoverflow will not let me post this question.

Comment: This probably has to do with privileges, specifically to access the directory. (Oracle privileges that is, not at the OS level.) You (the user running the anonymous block and creating the procedure) may have access to the directory through a role, not through a direct grant given specifically to that user (that is, to you). That is OK for users; but when accessing (READ or WRITE)  **from a stored (i.e. named, as opposed to anonymous) procedure**, roles are ignored, only the privileges given to a user (the user who created the procedure) by a **direct grant** are available.

Comment: Thanks, @mathguy, that worked like a champ.